# Event-driven GPIO on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

All of the examples that I've seen for reading GPIO in Mathematica use **polling loops** of the form:

```
While[ True,
  If[DeviceRead["GPIO", pin] ... (*meets some criterion*)
    (*do something*)
  ]
]
```

Instead of this, has anybody tried writing doing **event-driven** GPIO on Raspberry Pi?

For example, in the popular [GPIOzero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library in python, it is common to write things like:

```
from gpiozero import Button, LED
from signal import pause

button = Button(22)

def buttonAction1():
    print("Button is pressed")

def buttonAction2():
    print("Button is released")

button.when_pressed = buttonAction1
button.when_released = buttonAction2

pause()
```

where the functions get called when an event occurs (in this case, a button being pressed or released)

**Are there any examples of event-driven GPIO in Mathematica?**

I suppose this would be analogous to the notebook-related function [EventHandler](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) but for GPIO.

I suspect it has something to do with [SessionSubmit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SessionSubmit.html)  and 
[ContinuousTask](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuousTask.html) but [DeviceRead is a blocking function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeviceRead.html).

On the other hand, I suppose it might be possible to take advantage of [Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html) functionality (and more specifically DynamicModule) to  implement something like this.

Comment: How the event (like voltage changes) on GPIO is defined on hardware level of Rapsberry? Do it has any pre-defined interrupts?  I guess, there are not. The when_pressed method is realized as regular asking of the GPIO interface.

Answer (score 3):

My best attempt to "fake" a program style that looks like this using Dynamic:

```
isPressed[pin_Integer] := (# == 1) &@ First@DeviceRead["GPIO", pin] 

buttonAction[True] := With[{},
  DeviceWrite["GPIO", 17 -> 1];
  "Button is pressed"]

buttonAction[False] := With[{},
  DeviceWrite["GPIO", 17 -> 0];
  "Button is released"]

Dynamic[
 buttonAction@isPressed[22]]
```

In reality, I suspect it is doing polling behind the scenes....

Comment: Do we know at what rate the device is consulted?